# Last hitting in-battle minions

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm learning last hitting minions and get the advices to kill minions under my turret.

But I'm with problems **when my minion wave encounters the enemy minion wave**.

I think kind of "chaotic" to detect when last hit the minion because sometimes a lot of friendly minions attacks only one enemy minion, and the hp lowers very fast... Sometimes I think myself challenging my minions about who will last hit the enemy!

Another point is, when minions lines clashes (let's say by example, 6 allied vs 6 enemies) and each battle against each, the hp of all minions will low at same time, and (in theory) all 6 can die at same time. And potencially I will lose 5 minion kills! How do I to avoid this?

How do I to beat my minions when battling against enemy minion waves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfection comes with practice. Try to creat a custom game and practice last hiting when the minion waves are in the midle of the lane. It is also very important to learn how to last hit when the minions are under the enemy turret, or under your own.

With time you will find a way to last hit that is confortable for you. Personaly, i don't look at the actual health of the minions, instead, I try to pay attention at **how fast** the minions are losing hp. I try to stand near the minions that are losing hp faster, and hit them when I'm sure my damage will kill them.

If two or more minions are losing health at the same speed, you can kill them at the same time with some AoE hability, or if your damage is high enough, last hit one minion and let the other with hp enough to survive until you finish your attack, then simply last hit the other.

If you want, you can start practicing with meele champions, since they have higher AD. Champions like [Jarvan](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Jarvan_IV) and [Sion](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Sion) are able to last hit very easily. Champions which attacks have long animations times (normally AP ones) are more difficult to master, since you will have to consider the animation time when last hitting.

Also, keep moving, this will help you since you can get close to the right minions faster. And make you a more unpredictable target to the enemy.

Good luck in your training.

Answer (score 5):

I would say the 1st thing is experience :-D
The more you will last hit the more you will learn how to do it well and use some tricks.

Sometimes when multiple minions start do get low at the same time you can use AOE skills to clear them at the same time.

And finally if you play as AD carry, the support can help your last hitting by lowering a minion in order to make it ready to be last hit before another : For example to last hit mage minions under turret = 1 suppt hit + 1 tower hit + 1 Carry hit

you can also look this post : [Why does one side's minion wave push harder than the other side?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52111/why-does-one-sides-minion-wave-push-harder-than-the-other-side)

To help you understand how the minions "think" ;-)

Comment: very good answer

Comment: good answer, but alot of the times support will get yelled at for hitting the minion wave because it pushes faster. Ideally, unless there is a tower push, you want to let the minions do all the damage to keep the waves in the middle and just let the adc last hit.

Comment: Yes but when you have a support with you on skype and a support that know how you play it makes things easier ;-) my friend who i play with generaly takes tarik and sometimes use his passiv to get some mana or when the other carry is backing a leona shield + AOE skill like Graves buckshot will clean the wave very fast to crush the minion on the turret :-D

Answer (score 5):

Instead of looking at the health of minions (which you should occasionally do), you should look at the rate in which minions are losing health. If you are ADC, your support should lower the minion's health so you get cs (creep score) faster.

Comment: it's a small edit, but it uses the "correct" way to call it. CC is Crowd Control. And I never heard of ck (Creep Kill?). Being CS (Creep score, based on the score that you get by killing them) the more accurate way to say it.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking at which enemy minions are low, which is a common mistake.

You have to look at which minions are attacking which other minions and attack those targets. Note that ranged minions do a lot more damage, so you mostly have to focus on which target those are attacking.

It requires a ton of practice but once you get the hang of it, your creep score will improve a lot.